# Is there a query to find whether an object property exists or not in an ontology created in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege

Can anyone help me with a query that will return True if an object property exists in an ontology and false otherwise. FYI the ontology is created in Protege and no individuals are being added in it. But object property has been set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ASK` query:

```
ASK
WHERE {
   ?s <p> ?o .
}
```

Returns `true` if any triple matching the pattern exists, and `false` if there are no matches.

Comment: I don't think that this is what OP is looking for.  From the question, "FYI the ontology is created in Protege and no individuals are being added in it. But object property has been set."  I think OP is asking how to check whether the ontology contains a declaration for a particular object property.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, will try it and get back to you, i have already used ASK WHERE query but im unable to refer to a specific object property, how to refer to it in the query. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are no triples defined using the property, then you need to query for the property definition.  To find all defined object properties try `SELECT ?p WHERE {?p a owl:ObjectProperty}`.  From there you can define an `ASK` query for the specific property.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me with a query that will return True if an object
>   property exists in an ontology and false otherwise. FYI the ontology
>   is created in Protege and no individuals are being added in it. But
>   object property has been set.

If you've declared an object property **http://example.org/P** in an OWL ontology, then RDF serialization of the OWL ontology will contain the triple, **<http://example.org/P> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty**. (See [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language
Mapping to RDF Graphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/) for more about that mapping;  if you search for "ObjectProperty", then you'll quickly find this part of the mapping in Table 1.) To find out whether that triple exists in RDF document, you can use an **ASK** query in SPARQL:

```sql
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

ask { <http://example.org/P> a owl:ObjectProperty }
```